# I can not send emails to google GMAIL from my domain. My mails are blocked and I receive the following notification:

Tags: email, gmail, zimbra

I can not send mails from the google GMAIL domain.  My mails are blocked and I receive the following notification:

> host gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[64.233.166.26] said:
>       550-5.7.1 [89.30.96.175      12] Our system has detected that this message
>       is 550-5.7.1 likely unsolicited mail. To reduce the amount of spam sent to
>       Gmail, 550-5.7.1 this message has been blocked. Please visit 550-5.7.1
>       https://support.google.com/mail/?p=UnsolicitedMessageError 550 5.7.1  for
>       more information. v25si3291558wrv.174 - gsmtp (in reply to end of DATA
>       command)

PLease help me

Answer (score 1):

Is this to any gmail recipient, or just a specific one?

It's quite common for people to block a domain, especially if you've been ...  ahem  .. bad.

If you haven't been purposefully blocked, then I suggest you consider looking into firewall issues, antivirus, etc.  You know you could get this kind of error when you try to send the same message to too many people as well?  Try just one recipient, if you have multiple listed.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence in your post states "I can not send mails from the google GMAIL domain. My mails are blocked and I receive the following notification," but, because the error message that follows is coming from a Gmail server and you listed "Zimbra" as a tag for your post, I'm wondering if your first sentence is not misworded and that it should be "to the GMAIL domain" rather than "from the GMAIL domain." I'm assuming that is the case, since the [Zimbra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zimbra) software suite contains an email server component and I see the IP address listed by Gmail for the sending server is `89.30.96.175` and that takes me to a Zimbra page, if I access `http://89.30.96.175`/

It appears that Gmail may have placed that IP address on its block list, e.g., from [How to Test If an IP Address Is on Gmail's Blacklist](https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-test-if-an-ip-address-is-on-gmails-blacklist).

> If Google's put you on the blacklist, your network's email servers
>   will tell you. Gmail responds to blacklisted addresses by sending the
>   servers either a 421 error or a 550. The 421 is for temporary
>   problems; 550 indicates a complete block on mail originating from your
>   Internet address. You may need to contact your email provider to
>   research the servers. You can also enter your domain name on a website
>   such as MX Toolbox and see if the site reports a blacklist.

You can view the MX Toolbox check for the IP address on various [DNS-based Blackhole Lists (DNSBLs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNSBL) at [blacklist:89.30.96.175](https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=blacklist%3A89.30.96.175&run=toolpage). The IP address is currently on the [ZapBL](https://zapbl.net/lookup.php) list, which reports it has seen spam 4 times from that IP address since August 15, though I don't know if Google is using that list. I would suspect that Gmail isn't using that list, but has also adjudged some email from that IP address as spam due to its own checks of the content of email from that address. E.g., see the "Gmail Blacklist Criteria" section at [How to Remove Your IP from the Gmail Blacklist](https://www.rackaid.com/blog/gmail-blacklist-removal/). Try going to Google's support page at [My domain is having delivery problems with Gmail](https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/2920052?hl=en) troubleshooting page. Unfortunately, you probably won't be able to get the IP address removed immediately.

Comment: Indeed my first post was not well formulated that is why I corrected it

Comment: Thank for your help I will try to follow your instructions

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue but this article helped me out, mine was on AWS, and configuring the AWS Route 53 DNS records correctly can fix it.
Check this [article](https://medium.com/@korkotyan/namecheap-private-email-dns-records-setup-with-aws-route-53-7e71d2d9f486).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).